# NUnit constraint that negates what comes before it

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm trying to build a constraint that "works" only if some extra variable is true/false.

So I could use it like this:

```
Assert.That(animals, Is.SupersetOf(dogs).If(isSuperset));
```

The `Not` constraint negates what comes after, but there is no constraint to negates what comes before.

I have this so far:

```
public static Constraint If(this Constraint expression, bool isTrue)
{
  return ((Constraint)(((IResolveConstraint)expression).Resolve()))
         .And.Append(new EqualConstraint(isTrue).And.EqualTo(true));
}
```

But that doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: could you wrap the whole assert in an if?

Comment: @Joe_DM Yeah I could do that, but I'd like to perform the if/else within the assert, to make the test neater.

Comment: Just based on how method chaining works, it would be difficult to have a method on the right override a method on the left. The only way I can think to do that is if it's all deferred execution and then you somehow manually evaluate the expression before it's invoked. My initial suspicion is that it can't be done. But I'm happy to be wrong. I hope somebody has what you're looking for.

Comment: actually, just noticed that this does seem to be passing in expressions and so it is likely already a deferred execution where you can do this.

In your new constraint called `If` could you just return a passing result any time that `isTrue` is false?
e.g. Ignore the expresstion that was passed in, and just return a new Constraint that is always true, or success (however NUnit does it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that when If(false), you want the expression to always pass:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static Constraint If(this Constraint expression, bool isTrue)
    {
        return new IfConstraint(expression, isTrue);
    }

    public class IfConstraint : Constraint
    {
        private Constraint _linkedConstraint;
        private bool _isTrue;

        public IfConstraint(Constraint linkedConstraint, bool isTrue)
        {
            _linkedConstraint = linkedConstraint;
            _isTrue = isTrue;
        }

        public override ConstraintResult ApplyTo<TActual>(TActual actual)
        {
            if (!_isTrue)
                return new ConstraintResult(this, actual, true);
            return _linkedConstraint.ApplyTo<TActual>(actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already got an answer but since I already got a working POC I thought I'd share it anyway.

Heres what I did:

```
public class TheFooClass
{
    [Test]
    public void TheFooTest()
    {
        Assert.That(true, Is.True.If(false)); // passes
        Assert.That(true, Is.True.If(true)); // passes
        Assert.That(false, Is.True.If(false)); // passes
        Assert.That(false, Is.True.If(true)); // fails
    }
}

public static class AssertionExtensions
{
    public static Constraint If(this Constraint expression, bool isTrue)
    {
        return isTrue ? expression : new AlwaysTrue();
    }
}

public class AlwaysTrue : Constraint
{
    public override ConstraintResult ApplyTo<TActual>(TActual actual)
    {
        var trueResult = new ConstraintResult(new TrueConstraint(), true);
        trueResult.Status = ConstraintStatus.Success;
        return trueResult;
    }
}
```